Lower case greek letters in Unicode not working in lualatex
Translating the following with lualatex:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Ωω
\end{document}

I get the message
Missing character: There is no ω (U+03C9) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!

In the resulting pdf, the upper case omega is there, but not the lower case one. That's a bit surprising, I would expect either both to work or none.
Adding packages like fontspec doesn't change anything.
Is there a way to make the lower case omega work, too?

Where do you want to take it from if it does not exist in the font?

@mickep I don't know. For that reason I opened this question.

Odd that running albatross ω shows latin modern contains the symbol

@mbert Only Latin Modern Math does

@egreg Makes sense but why does albatross ω print all the latin modern variants, e.g. LMRoman10-Regular,LM Roman 10 Regular,Latin Modern Roman 10 Regular ?

@mbert I don't see them if I run albatross ω

@egreg Seems like a windows problem. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/732063/208544

@mbert I'm a very happy Windows nonuser.

The simplest is to load a font with the glyphs (e.g.  \setmainfont{Free Serif}); the only drawback of this method is when you notice the difference with the default font (and this does matter).

Latin Modern Roman only has capital Greek letters (likely taken from the Computer Modern text font).
Choose a different font with fontspec.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicodefonttable}

\begin{document}

\displayfonttable[range-start=0370,range-end=03FF]{lmroman10-regular.otf}

\end{document}


If you replace the font with NewCM10-Regular.otf you get


Thank you for this answer. I don't want to change the font globally. Is there a way to add the missing symbols from another font?

There are several options. One of them is babel, which fully supports Unicode and OpenType, but maybe it’s a sledgehammer to crack a nut:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{greek}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{NewComputerModern10}
\begin{document}
text Ωω text
\end{document}



If you are using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTex, you can add to your preamble the line
\usepackage[olddefault]{fontsetup}

to load a version of the default font which includes lowercase Greek letters. fontsetup also loads unicode-math, if I remember correctly.
You can play around with it a little — e.g. loading the package with no options loads a Book version of the default font, which is in my opinion slightly nicer to read.
Edit: just to be clear, if you use the [olddefault] option, the font is identical to the standard LaTeX font.
