albatross output for character and codepoint differ
Looking at this question, I wanted to know which fonts contain ω (U+03C9) using albatross. In my Windows terminal I ran albatross ω which produced a very long list of fonts, including all the Latin Modern variants. Here's a sample.
│ LMRoman10-Italic,LM Roman 10 Italic,Latin Modern Roman 10 Italic            │
│ LMRoman10-Regular,LM Roman 10 Regular,Latin Modern Roman 10 Regular         │
│ LMRoman12-Bold,LM Roman 12 Bold,Latin Modern Roman 12 Bold                  │
│ LMRoman12-Italic,LM Roman 12 Italic,Latin Modern Roman 12 Italic            │
│ LMRoman12-Regular,LM Roman 12 Regular,Latin Modern Roman 12 Regular         │
│ LMRoman17-Regular,LM Roman 17 Regular,Latin Modern Roman 17 Regular         │
│ LMRoman5-Bold,LM Roman 5 Bold,Latin Modern Roman 5 Bold                     │
│ LMRoman5-Regular,LM Roman 5 Regular,Latin Modern Roman 5 Regular            │
│ LMRoman6-Bold,LM Roman 6 Bold,Latin Modern Roman 6 Bold                     │
│ LMRoman6-Regular,LM Roman 6 Regular,Latin Modern Roman 6 Regular            │
│ LMRoman7-Bold,LM Roman 7 Bold,Latin Modern Roman 7 Bold                     │
│ LMRoman7-Italic,LM Roman 7 Italic,Latin Modern Roman 7 Italic               │
│ LMRoman7-Regular,LM Roman 7 Regular,Latin Modern Roman 7 Regular            │
│ LMRoman8-Bold,LM Roman 8 Bold,Latin Modern Roman 8 Bold                     │
│ LMRoman8-Italic,LM Roman 8 Italic,Latin Modern Roman 8 Italic               │
│ LMRoman8-Regular,LM Roman 8 Regular,Latin Modern Roman 8 Regular            |

and so on.
But from the question and egreg's answer, Latin Modern text fonts do not contain this symbol. So I tried with the explicit codepoint and got the correct list. Running albatross U+03C9 shows Latin Modern Math contains the symbol but the text fonts do not.
Is this reproducible on other OS's? A bug in albatross? A misunderstanding on my part of how albatross works? It doesn't matter which terminal I use on my Windows machine.

Not reproducible for me on Linux.

@Skillmon Thanks for checking

I think Windows terminal doesn't support Unicode by default. You need to enable it using the chcp command. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/388500

on macOS the outputs differ solely in one line Unicode glyph with code points [3C9] in one case Unicode glyph with code points [03C9] in the other.

Reported with an edit to mention @michal.h21's comment: https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/albatross/-/issues/15
